# Powershell: System.Object[] in export-csv file

Tags: powershell, azure, csv, export, export-csv

I wrote this script to generate a csv file:

```
$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM
$vmOutput = @()
$VMs | ForEach-Object { 
  $tmpObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
  $tmpObj | Add-Member -MemberType Noteproperty -Name "VM Name" -Value $_.Name
  $tmpObj | Add-Member -MemberType Noteproperty -Name "VM Type" -Value $_.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType
  $tmpObj | Add-Member -MemberType Noteproperty -Name "VM Profile" -Value $_.HardwareProfile.VmSize
  $tmpObj | Add-Member -MemberType Noteproperty -Name "VM OS Disk Size" -Value $_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.DiskSizeGB
  $tmpObj | Add-Member -MemberType Noteproperty -Name "VM Data Disk Size" -Value $_.StorageProfile.DataDisks.DiskSizeGB
  $vmOutput += $tmpObj
}
$vmOutput | export-csv C:\Users\***\data.csv -delimiter ";" -force -notypeinformation
```

But as the last column VM Data Disk Size stores one than more data (there can be multiple disks) in file they're presented as `System.Object[]`. How can I force powershell to join this data into a single string?

I tried to add `-join` parameter after `$tmpObj` in line 9 ad after `$vmoutput` in last line, but there were no satisfactory results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always tricky to try to convert hierarchical data into structured data. Something like this should actually work:

```
$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM
$vmOutput = $VMs | ForEach-Object { 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "VM Name" = $_.Name
        "VM Type" = $_.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType
        "VM Profile" = $_.HardwareProfile.VmSize
        "VM OS Disk Size" = $_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.DiskSizeGB
        "VM Data Disk Size" = ($_.StorageProfile.DataDisks.DiskSizeGB) -join ','
    }
}
$vmOutput | export-csv C:\Users\***\data.csv -delimiter ";" -force -notypeinformation
```

I just cannot test - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this either but can this also work?

```
$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM
$vmOutput = $VMs | ForEach-Object { 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "VM Name" = $_.Name
        "VM Type" = $_.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType
        "VM Profile" = $_.HardwareProfile.VmSize
        "VM OS Disk Size" = $_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.DiskSizeGB
        "VM Data Disk Size" = $_.StorageProfile.DataDisks.DiskSizeGB | Out-String
    }
}
$vmOutput | export-csv C:\Users\***\data.csv -delimiter ";" -force -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Not really as this shows only the first value, removing the other ones.