# Variable property of Powershell function output does not work as expected

Tags: azure, powershell, variables, properties, export-csv

I'm using Get-Diskfree function described here: https://binarynature.blogspot.com/2010/04/powershell-version-of-df-command.html

I want to sum all values from *Used* column, but as I try to call out a specific properties of Get-Diskfree output, I've got nothing, null.

Function is showing output like this:

```
FileSystem : NTFS
Type       : Local Fixed Disk
Volume     : C:
Available  : somevalue
Computer   : somevalue
Used       : somevalue
Size       : somevalue

FileSystem : NTFS
Type       : Local Fixed Disk
Volume     : D:
Available  : somevalue
Computer   : somevalue
Used       : somevalue
Size       : somevalue
```

I want to be able to call out *Used* property by parsing Get-Diskfree output into variable like this:

```
function {...}
$variable = Get-Diskfree
$variable.Used
```

Last line don't give me any output, in comparision to for example:

```
$variable = get-service
$variable.Name
long list of service names
```

Is function (or functions overall) designed in a way, that this method is impossible to use?

I plan to sum them by using more less the method I used in this script [Powershell: System.Object[] in export-csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099068/powershell-system-object-in-export-csv-file)

What I want to achieve is to sum *Used* column for first 8 disks (there are 20 of them on VM), export an output as csv and send an html email based on that csv file.

Comment: `$variable = Get-Diskfree;$variable.Used` worked for me

Comment: To get the first 8 objects from `Get-Diskfree`, use `$variable = Get-Diskfree | Select-Object -First 8`. To get the sum of the `Used` column, this should do it:  `$totalUsed = $variable | Measure-Object Used -sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum`

Comment: does the code @ line 55-57 work when you call it against your VM? just that code, not any other part - this is for diagnostic testing. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes it works when run locally on vm.

Comment: @ArcSet Okay my bad, it actually works when I run it locally on this vm. Doesn't work when connected to Azure supscription on my local pc.

Comment: @lubierzca - i didn't ask if it ran ON the vm. [*grin*] does it run _against_ the VM? can you run the command on your system **_with the VM name in the `-ComputerName $computer` parameter_** and get a result back. if NOT, then you likely have found the problem ... that cmdlet may not work when called against a remote VM for some reason. ///// the fix is to switch to something that does work ... such as using `Invoke-Command` to run the code _on the remote system_.